# Style binding doesn't work with HTML image elements (Vue.js)

Tags: javascript, html, css

In Vue, I'm trying to use style binding for the CSS "top" property of an HTML image element:

```
<img src="../assets/myimg.png" id="myimg" v-bind:style="[!ended ? 'top:20%' : 'top:80%']">
```

Here's the CSS for the image:

```
#myimg{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 10px;
    left: 10%;
  }
```

"ended" is just a prop that this component receives from its parent. If it's false, the "top" property of the image should be 20%, otherwise, it should be 80%.

Unfortunately, the image stays at the same position regardless of whether "ended" is true or false. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

Here's the complete docs for style binding in Vue.js:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax-1

In your case, you can use the object syntax:

```
<img src="../assets/myimg.png" id="myimg" v-bind:style="{ top: !ended ? '20%' : '80%'}">
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: But what if I wanted to set 2 CSS properties? I know I can just define a style object in data and use that. But what if I wanted to place it inline instead of referencing an object from data? For example, the following code didn't work: `v-bind:style="{ top,visibility: !ended ? '20%,visible' : '80%,hidden'}"` How would I rewrite this to make it work?

Comment: @Vktr Similar to normal objects, you have to input different properties as `{ prop1: val1, prop2: val2, prop3: val3 }` and so on... So to add the visibility property to the above code: `<img src="../assets/myimg.png" id="myimg" v-bind:style="{ top: !ended ? '20%' : '80%', visibility: !ended ? 'visible' : 'hidden' }">` .

Answer (score 0):

Try writing it inside brackets,

```
<img src="../assets/myimg.png" id="myimg" v-bind:style="[!ended ? {'top':'20%'} : {'top':'80%'}]">
```

Answer (score 0):

Altenatively you can use this method:

```
<img src="../assets/myimg.png" id="myimg" v-bind:style="'top:' + (!ended ? '20%' : '80%')">
```

Or if you want to use es6 template literals:

```
<img src="../assets/myimg.png" id="myimg" v-bind:style="`top: ${!ended ? '20%' : '80%'}`">
```

The third altenative would be to add the dynamic style to a [computed property](https://v1.vuejs.org/guide/computed.html) as follows:

```
<img src="../assets/myimg.png" id="myimg" v-bind:style="dynamicStyle">
```

then in your script add the following code:

```
computed: {
  dynamicStyle() {
    return {
      top: !this.ended ? '20%' : '80%'
    }
  }
}
```